# Merge shapefiles without creating extra fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, merge

I have a road shapefile with fields like line, name, line id, line type (like nh,sh) etc.

I also have another line shapefile which is the updated one of the older one. Here one line is changed from nh to sh and vice-versa. I want to know how can I merge the new shapefile with the older one without increasing the the number of fields. I have been doing it manually.

Is there  any tool to help me out or any short-cut procedure?

Rectifying 100s of lines is taking too much time.

Comment: So you want the number and type of fields the same as the older shapefile? Sounds like a field mapping issue? When you run the merge tool you need to set the field mapping parameter, this is you saying that field from new shapefile will merge into older field. Suggest you read the help file for this tool and have a play but on BACKED UP data.

Comment: In the Merge tool there's an optional 'field map' where you can modify your fields

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be the Data>Load option:

1. Create geodatabase and import target shp (to feature class (fc))
2. In Catalog, right click on target fc and select Load>Load Data

This option will allow you to manually define the field mapping for those field names that do not match between the to-be-merged shp and the target fc.  Once loaded, you may right click on the "merged" target fc in Catalog and export back to shp.